# Timezone is correct but Time is not - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

I'm making a little twitter clone just for learning and I came across a problem where, before **and** after allowing users to select the timezone they are in, the time displaying when they would tweet a certain thing was wrong.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
/* current date/time whenever they send a tweet */

    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

/* Insert into db as `time` */


/* Time retrieved as $value['time'] & users timezone as $_SESSION['timezone'] */
/* Convert to users timezone */

    $users_timezone = new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['timezone']);
    $date = new DateTime($value['time']);
    $date->setTimeZone($users_timezone);
    $new_date = $date->format('M j, o g:i a e');
    echo $new_date;
```

It is currently 11:32am here in the LA area, yet after conversion it shows 6:26pm

My default is in Berlin, which it is currently 8:33pm but before conversion it shows 1am

Can anyone give me any insight into this? First time doing this.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['timezone']`?  Also, you're not actually storing the time into the database as a `VARCHAR` are you?  You should probably store it as a `DATETIME`, and it should be in UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check System Time**

Please check your current system time of your server by running `date` via ssh.

I believe php gets the date from the system therefore if your system time is incorrect then your php time would also be incorrect.

**Check `$value['time']`**

You are using the construct method within the DataTime class. Here is the documentation for that method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Make sure `$value['time']` is in an acceptable format. On way to do this easily is to use the `strtotime` function. This will make a unix timestamp from `$value['time']` and that will probably satisfy the construct method of the DateTime class.

Comment: just did and it is displaying the right time. Still cant figure out whats wrong!

Comment: Can you `echo $value['time']`? Then trying changing this line `$date = new DateTime($value['time']);` to `$date = new DateTime(strtotime($value['time']));`